# Microsoft Edge and IE11 doesn't invoke servlet

Tags: servlets, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I'm testing an existing web app from a Windows 10 environment.
Current versions of Firefox, Chrome and Opera work as expected but Edge and IE11 don't.

The welcome page (html) of the app displays correctly but when submit is invoked nothing happens i.e doesn't move off welcome page and run the servlet. There are no error messages, no relevant server log entries. When I run the app from within a NetBeans IDE the monitor shows only the requests for the welcome page, none for the servlet request.

The symptoms are the same for Tomcat and Glassfish.

IE9 on a Windows XP system works so, for fun, I played with x-ua-compatible settings in the welcome page html but no resolution.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the browsers network inspector (or Fiddler) to determine if the request is sent at all, and if so how it differs from a working example/what the corresponding response is?  If its not sent its an issue with your client side code which we cannot see.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Both the browser network monitor and Fiddler say the same thing as the IDE - no request is sent to the servlet. Without getting too philosophical, the browsers are the only client side code here. I think I was hoping for some obscure browser setting to explain why IE11 and Edge don't work and the other browsers do. Thanks anyway.

Comment: So must be an HTML or JavaScript problem then

Comment: I work on the Microsoft Edge team, and would love to see the client-side code being delivered to both IE and Edge. Can you share a direct link to an instance of your app, or perhaps the code delivered to the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Sampson - playing around with the welcome html file, I have found a solution. The original code segment was

```
<div class ="text">
 <form id="plant_select" action="Search">
    <input name="name" placeholder="enter name" class="inputtext" autofocus required>
 </form>
 <p style = "padding-top:20px"><input type="submit" value="Search" form="plant_select"></p>
</div>
```

By moving the submit line into the form tag thus

```
<div class ="text">
 <form id="plant_select" action="Search">
    <input name="name" placeholder="enter name" class="inputtext" autofocus required>
    <p style = "padding-top:20px"><input type="submit" value="Search" form="plant_select"></p>
 </form>
</div>
```

The app now works for IE11 and Edge.

The original code worked for all available browsers at the time and was passed by an HTML5 validator. Hope this is of interest to you.

Comment: This code answers the problem; you were relying on the `[form] attribute`, a relatively new feature to the HTML standard. While not presently supported in Microsoft Edge, [our team is currently giving it serious consideration](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/formattribute?filter=f3f0000bf&search=form attribute), and we'll likely start development for a future release.